# Can I decrement a define value at each repeat of itself at compile time?

Tags: c, c99

Such as this:

```
#define ERROR_CODE_A -1
#define ERROR_CODE_B -2
#define ERROR_CODE_C -3
```

but this way:

```
#define ERROR_CODE_A DEFINE_TRICK(start_value)
#define ERROR_CODE_B DEFINE_TRICK(start_value)
#define ERROR_CODE_C DEFINE_TRICK(start_value)
```

where start_value may be some define trick so that multiple usage of it decreases itself.

I couldn't find anything but it can help in a situation where there will be hundreds of error codes and adding a new error code between two breaks continuous value mapping such as

```
#define ERROR_CODE_XY  -1234
#define ERROR_CODE_XZ  -1235
#define ERROR_CODE_NEW -3455 <---- how can I make this derived automatically?
#define ERROR_CODE_ZW  -1236 <---- so that this and all following are changed
```

Comment: Why not just use an `enum`?

Comment: You mean anonymous enums then.

Comment: Named or unnamed, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: And if I use multiple enums, all elements of enums combined will have unique values right?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: All these defines I need them scattered to different places such as definitions of a scripting engine command definitions so a command is easily found with its error code and error code is found with its address pointer of an array and all related things together. But enum needs all its values together in one place but here, if I use multiple enums to keep readability, do I need to initialize each enum block myself or is there an easy way to make all of them unique valued?

Comment: I feel your approach isn't really useful as it seems to change error codes the moment you'd inserted another code. This would mean you'd need to adjust the documentation for all those codes which changed. This you do not really want to do. And for the case that you do not maintain documentation for the error codes, why use different codes at all?

Comment: Actually, everything is going to be calculated by a different thread(opencl) and I need to distribute different commands and error handling to different threads with different numbers(as workitem id values, for example). Other than that, not only error values but also command values need to be different. So if one command fails, it will signal a local thread to handle the error(such as rendering an error message concurrently on a texture).

Comment: GCC has a `__COUNTER__` preprocessor macro that counts instances, but you do not want to use it—it will be difficult to manage in situations like this. Typically, problems of this sort are solved by using a separate program to manage the identifiers. You would have a list of identifiers in some file, and you would write a program to read that file and produce a header file (e.g., `ErrorCodes.h`) that defines the error codes. This program would be compiled and run at build time, before compiling your other code. The your other source files would include the header.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you Eric Postpischil. I'll try the dynamic header file solution of yours.